# 70 6-sided dice Question re: Gaming

Tags: probability, dice

I play a game where a d6 (a regular, fair 6 sided die) is used to determine whether or not a weapon hits an opponent's vehicle.  There is one possible scenario where the attacker can roll 70d6 in one attack step.  A "hit" is scored on a 4, 5 or 6 on each die.  In other words, you roll all dice, look at each and count up the 4's, 5's and 6's.  A 4 counts as 1 hit and a 5 counts as 1 hit while a 6 counts as 2 hits.

Question 1 - What is the probability of scoring at least 20 hits when rolling this 70d6 attack?

Question 2 - How does the probability change if a 3 is also 1 hit?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that not everyone is familiar with die game notation. 30d6 means you throw 30 standard (assumed fair) six-sided dice.

Comment: Generating functions work as well as anything here.  You are interested in the coefficients of $\frac {(4+2x+x^2)^{30}}{6^{30}}$.  You'll want to use [a computer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+(1%2F6%5E30)*(4%2B2x%2Bx%5E2)%5E30)

Comment: Would anyone be able to explain why this post got voted down?  I would like to make sure I meet the criteria expected of this forum next time I post.  Thank you.

Comment: @Lulu - THank you.  By coefficients, do you mean solving for X when the equation = 0?

Comment: No, those would be roots.  I mean the coefficients. For instance, the probability of getting a score of exactly $20$ is the coefficient of $x^{20}$.  Note:  you changed the number of dice to $70$...my calculation is for $30$.

Comment: Note:  I mistyped in my first comment.  It should have been $\frac {(3+2x+x^2)^{30}}{6^{30}}$.  If you really want $70$ dice then  replace $30$ with $70$, but with that many dice the probability of getting a score of at least $20$ is essentially $1$.

Comment: Suggestion: Find the mean and variance of the score from a single die.  Then use the central limit theorem to find an approximation to the total score from the 70 dice.

Comment: You’re describing the cumulative distribution function of a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). With that large a number of dice, a normal approximation, as suggested by @awkward, is a much more convenient way to compute these probabilities. You can read about that in the linked Wikipedia article, too.

Comment: No downvotes evident now. Generally we're looking to see what you have tried and what progress you have made. That gives us a clue at what mathematical level to answer. // Answers by lulu and @awkward seem useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approximation by simulation:
In a million sessions of 70 rolls of the die according to Question 1,
I found that it is almost sure to score at least 20 hits. [Notice I have labeled die faces with the appropriate numbers of hits; R treats the three `0`'s as different faces.]

```
set.seed(926); m = 10^6
die = c(0,0,0,1,1,2); rolls=70
hits = replicate(m, sum(sample(die,rolls,rep=T)))
mean(hits >= 20)
[1] 0.999998
```

If you intended 30 rolls of the die (as mentioned in a comment), then
its a little over 50%.

```
set.seed(926); m = 10^6
die = c(0,0,0,1,1,2); rolls=30
hits = replicate(m, sum(sample(die,rolls,rep=T)))
mean(hits >= 20)
[1] 0.540681
```

Either way, I suggest you try the CLT method proposed by @awkward.
Seventy rolls, or even 30, should be enough to get a reasonably good
approximation. Then you can compare results from the CLT with results from
simulation.

*Note:* Here is a histogram (blue) for the number of hits in 70 rolls, along with the
best-fitting normal curve (orange). The fit is not perfect, but is surely good
enough to show that there is almost no probability below 20.

```
# for rolls=70
mu = mean(hits);  sg = sd(hits);  mu;  sg
[1] 46.66131
[1] 6.235426
hist(hits, prob=T, col="skyblue2", ylim=c(0,.07))
curve(dnorm(x, mu, sg), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The expected number of hits is just $70$ times the expected number for one die.  For $4,5,6$ hitting, you expect $\frac 46$ hit per die or $\frac {4\cdot 70}6=41\frac23$ hits on average per roll.  If a $3$ hits as well, you now expect $\frac 56$ from one die, for a total of $58\frac 13$ per roll.  The chance of scoring at least $20$ is very high in either case.  We can approximate the distribution with a normal one.  For the first case the variance of one die is $\frac 16\cdot (4+1+1)-(\frac 23)^2=\frac 59$ so the variance of the whole roll is $70\cdot \frac 59=39\frac 19$ and the standard deviation is about $6$.  The first is over $3$ standard deviations low, which happens less than once in $600$ tries.  The other is even more likely to yield at least $20$ hits.